# Video formats in Blender

Tags: animation, file-format

I am new to blender and I am trying to create an intro video for my site.

I have rendered the animation and want to compile the images for the animation so that I can use it in my video editor (Davinci Resolve 15).

I used the video sequencer to compile them into an AVI format but Resolve is not recognizing the file.

In a tutorial that I have watched, that helped me so far, the guy opened the formats drop-down in the output area and it had several other formats that are not a part of the release that I have (2.79b) including H.264, MPEG, and Ogg Theora.

He was using v 2.71. How do I get those other formats to work in Blender? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the image sequence directly in Da Vinci?

Comment: @Leander is right, If you are using Resolve, you can spare yourself the pain of using the VSE, and load the image sequence directly into resolve and edit directly without having to encode them first.